# Case-insensitive distinct in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, distinct

i was trying to list all distinct values form a column using laravel. Here's the code

```
Model::distinct()->lists('model_make_id')
```

But it case -sesnsitive. It detects `Audi` and `audi` differenty. How to make it case-insensitive?

Comment: Quick tip when dealing with DB issues, get the underlying query! `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` after the query is executed to see what was run against the database to get your results.

Comment: Shouldn't this be related to the collation set on the table and column?

Comment: @oskarth I'm a newbie in this field. Can you explain what are you trying to say?

Comment: Model::distinct()->lists('model_make_id') - fetching unique results.

Comment: @sgt Yes. It's fetching unique results, but now i want to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: what out put do you want?

Comment: I want `Audi`. For example: if there is `hello-world` and `Hello-World`. i want `Hello-World`

Comment: are they different from each other?

Comment: Yes. Table has around 65k enteries. Every vehicle has model description, name, weight etc . Some rows has `audi` and some has `Audi`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a raw query like this:

```
Model::selectRaw("DISTINCT UPPER(model_make_id) as model")->lists('model')
```

This way Audi and audi will be considered as the same once uppercase.
But there's probably a better way.